# Which browser does "Pinterest 0" in W3Counter's browser marketshare stats refer to?

Tags: browser

I keep an eye on [W3Counter](http://www.w3counter.com/), which provides information about web browser usage. They also keep statistics of worldwide browser market share, showing the percentages of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.

To my surprise, their [December 2015 global market share report](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php?year=2015&month=12) says that the 8th most commonly used browser was "Pinterest 0" with an astounding 2.50% of global market share (ahead of Chrome 38 and Android 4).

This clearly isn't the Pinterest website itself because websites don't generate a User Agent string. There must be some web browser app that is identifying itself as a Pinterest web browser.

I did a bit of searching and it doesn't look like Pinterest has created a web browser to compete with Chrome et al.. So what does this record mean in W3Counter's browser market share stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So what does this record mean in W3Counter's browser market share stats?

Pinterest has built an experimental new web browser. It is currently live in Japan.

> For a week this summer, Pinterest’s design and engineering teams
>   huddled to conceptualize, design, and build an experimental new web
>   browser intended to increase the volume and relevance of content
>   posted to its platform.
>
> The browser, currently live in Japan, supports normal browsing but
>   contains a special feature: When a Pinterest user wants to pin images
>   from a site they’re visiting in the browser, they can hit a button
>   that strips out everything but the images from the web page they’re
>   on, adds share buttons, and creates a quick route to pin these images
>   to the platform.
>
> The browser, called the “Save Tab,” lives within Pinterest’s main app
>   and has been active for a few months. **Outside of its special
>   abilities, the tab is a functional browser built on WebKit, the layout
>   engine used in Apple’s Safari.**
>
> [image: ...]

Source [Pinterest Built A New, Experimental Browser](http://www.buzzfeed.com/alexkantrowitz/pinterest-is-experimenting-with-a-unique-new-browser)

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down! Fascinating to find that this is indeed a real web browser (in the technical sense of the term) that has climbed so quickly in global marketshare.